# Can I create thread safe objects with ContextBoundObject?

Tags: .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I have an object that serves multiple requests (threads) ... think of SqlConnection object across multiple threads ....

Now, I want to create a "Thread" safe object which is aware of the thread context in which it is *created*.

So if Thread1 creates object foo and Thread2 tries to access it .... object foo would ignore it and only "act" if Thread1 was running ...

Will ContextBoundObject do this? if yes, what are its limitations?

Pseudo code

```
public class Foo
{       
   private int _threadId; 

   public void DoSomething()
   {
       (if thread.ManagedThreadId != _threadId) return;

      // Do some thread safe stuff
   }

}
```

Comment: Before going into how to do this? can you provide details on why you want to do this? maybe there are better solutions to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to do this because I want to have "Thread-Safe" instances ... including method calls and properties access. 
I don't believe in "This object is not safe for multi-threaded access".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behavior you want to achieve can be made by using [SynchronizationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.contexts.synchronizationattribute.aspx).

However, using this attribute will serialize access to all members of the class. On the other hand if some methods of the class do not require synchronization (like static method that do not share any state) using Synchronization attribute may result in degraded performance.

Comment: So the only option to achieve "auto" thread safety has performance issues !

Comment: @JalalEl-Shaer *Any* option to achieve thread safety has performance issues. At the very least, it will mean that some parts of your code can't execute in parallel. If it did not have any implications, do you think that there would be any thread-unsafe objects in .NET? :D

Comment: @Luaan I believe all objects should be thread-safe and have the best possible performance. :D

Comment: @JalalEl-Shaer Don't we all? :P The thing is, thread-unsafe objects like this allow you to handle thread-safety the way you need it to. For example, if you're just working with a local SqlConnection, it's a waste to do any synchronization. In fact, it's very much possible to write your application in a way that *everything* is local (or immutable), keeping other threads from ever touching something on a different thread (it still looks like one of the best ways to achieve relatively painless parallelism). If you want to be thread-safe, don't use multiple threads :P

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve the thread safety by implementing ContextBoundObject and annotating the class with Synchronization attribute. However this is recommended only if you want class level locking (i.e. for all methods/properties etc.) and due to that at times it's prone to deadlock and poor concurrency.

The better solution in cases when only few methods need locking is to have manual lock in place using lock keyword that is abstract, lightweight and less exposed to deadlocks.

Hope this helps!!